# How to resume a Prefect flow on failure without having to re-run the entire flow?

Tags: python, prefect

## TL;DR;

I wasn't able to use prefect's [FlowRunner](https://docs.prefect.io/api/latest/engine/flow_runner.html#flowrunner-2) to solve the above question.  I likely either used it wrong (see below) or missed something.  Would really appreciate any pointers!

---

## The Problem

I read through the fantastic [prefect core documentation](https://docs.prefect.io/core/) and found the sections on [Handling Failure](https://docs.prefect.io/core/tutorial/04-handling-failure.html) and [Local Debugging](https://docs.prefect.io/core/advanced_tutorials/local-debugging.html) to be the most relevant to this (may have missed something!). The [FlowRunner](https://docs.prefect.io/api/latest/engine/flow_runner.html#flowrunner-2) class appeared (to me) to be the solution.

To see if I could use Flow Runner to resume a failed flow:

- Made a failing flow run:

```py
from time import sleep

import prefect
from prefect import Flow, task


@task
def success():
    sleep(3)
    return


@task
def failure():
    return 1 / 0


def get_flow_runner():
    with Flow("Success/Failure") as flow:

        success()
        failure()

    return prefect.engine.FlowRunner(flow)
```

- Ran it in iPython and saved the state:

```py
In [1]: run nameofscript.py
In [2]: flow_runner = get_flow_runner()
In [3]: state = flow_runner.run()
```

- Replaced 1 / 0 with 1 / 1 in `failure()` so task would be successful:
- And finally passed the previous state to the `flow_runner` hoping that it would resume the flow:

```py
In [1]: run nameofscript.py
In [2]: flow_runner = get_flow_runner()
In [3]: flow_runner.run(task_states=state.result)
```

The entire flow ran again including the 3 second successful task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that you are rebuilding your Flow with each run, which changes the Task objects.  `state.result` is a dictionary whose keys are Task objects - if the underlying Task object changes in any way, so will its hash.  You should instead manually create the dictionary of states using the updated Task objects, like so:

```py
from prefect.engine.state import Success

failure_task = runner.flow.get_tasks(name="failure")[0]
task_states = {failure_task: Success("Mocked success")}
```

Comment: Thanks @chriswhite this solves the above example! I tried this in a new scenario where tasks pass data, and my mocked success was overridden.  There's a section on checkpointing with result handlers in the prefect docs, could this be used to resume a flow at a broken task?

Comment: Could you share the code? If I had to guess you have multiple tasks named "failure" in your other example.  FYI to mock data passage you can use `Success("Mocked data", result=42)` or whatever the data may be.